# wanted to have a single list instead of multiple list showing prime numbers

Tags: python, list, primes

I tried to make a program that shows all prime number till the limit
but the code shows each factor adding to the `ans` list.
How do I fix this?

```
limit = 34
num = [value for value in range(2, limit + 1)]
factor = 2
ans = []
while True:
    if factor not in num:
        factor += 1
    elif factor in num:
        ans.append(factor)
        for ele in num:
            if ele % factor == 0:
                num.remove(ele)
        print(ans)
```

**Expected Output**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop - i.e., there is no condition that would cause the *while* loop to break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the `factor` variable is bounded.

```
limit = 34
num = list(range(2, limit + 1))
factor = 2
ans = []
while factor <= limit+1:
    if factor not in num:
        factor += 1
    elif factor in num:
        ans.append(factor)
        for ele in num:
            if ele % factor == 0:
                num.remove(ele)
print(ans)
```